# I've got a funky tab delimited file that I'd like to make less funky

Tags: python, csv

I have a lot of tab delimited data that is organized into multiple rows and should be all in two rows. Now it looks like this:

```
    Some Key    Other key   Foo Key    Bar Key
     0           5           18         12

    More Key    Dor key     Gee Key    Francis Scott  Key
     19          14          8          0

    Wa Key      Whis key    Don Key    Luh Key
     0           2           8          16
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
    Some Key    Other key   Foo Key    Bar Key    More Key    Dor key     Gee Key    Francis Scott  Key    Wa Key      Whis key    Don Key    Luh Key
     0           5           18         12         19          14          8          0                    0           2           8          16
```

I've got a few hundred csv files with about 20 rows each, 30 columns, so I want to script my way through this as much as possible. I'm using [Python CSV](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/csv.html#module-csv), but I can't figure out how to explain myself to it.

Comment: My only thought is that you may have to make two passes: once to convert to the horizontal format, and then a second to go to the vertical (assuming you can't do it in one step). Separating the two logics can make the solution easier to see. Good Luck!

Comment: @PeterRowell the hard part is saying "for each new row of text, pick that up and move it to the end of the top row" -- took out the part about transposing it when I'm done.

Comment: am i missing something or could you just get rid of every alternate (~) line ending (i.e. the `\n`)

Comment: @malangi I don't think that would help. That would give me four columns of keys and four columns of of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import csv
import sys

keys = []
values = []

reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter="\t")
for row in reader:
    keys.extend(row)
    values.extend(next(reader))

    # skip empty line
    assert next(reader, []) == []

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter="\t")
writer.writerow(keys)
writer.writerow(values)
```

Save this as thingie.py and run it with `python thingie.py < sample.csv` (where "sample.csv" is your data file)

Comment: Nice! There might be an extra TAB that shows up in there (at least in my test of it there was), but otherwise very nice.

Comment: I sanitized the example data before testing this. What's posted here isn't actually tab-delimited, but I assume the real data is.

Comment: Yes, the real data is tab delimited.

Comment: Very nice. I only have two questions. Are there multiple multi-line records in the data file? If so, this will jam them all together on one line. Second, does each multi-line record have the same keys?

Comment: @SpencerRathbun It really does look like the data above: one line of keys, followed by a line of values. Followed by a blank line, and then a new line of different keys followed by a line of corresponding values. (repeat x8). So I do want two lines: a line of keys and a line of values. This works great so far.

Comment: I edited this script to add an assertion that the supposedly empty line really is empty. Adding these sorts of checks to your code is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could ssplit the contents of your file with the tab as a separator, taking every int"eger element and putting it in one array, and taking every string element and putting it in another one. Then, you put out all the strings (keys) on one line separated by tabs, and one line containing all the integers separated by tabs.